# get Object Context in ExpressJS http (GET, POST etc) function callback

Tags: node.js, express

I am making a module where i need to do something like bellow

```
//myModule.js

var myModuleWrapper = function(){

  return {
     counter : 0,
     countIt: function( req, res, next ){
        this.counter++; // here i got ReferenceError: counter is not defined at countIt
        res.end(this.counter);
     }
  }
}

module.exports = function(){
  return new MyModuleWrapper();
}

//app.js
var myModule = require(./myModule.js);
app.get('/', mymodule.countIt);
```

How to get the context of returned object in commented line of my above code? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use `bind` method on the callback function.

Change `app.get('/', mymodule.countIt);` to:

```
app.get('/', mymodule.countIt.bind(mymodule));
```